# How to install cryptodome using Pip?

Tags: python, pip

When I try `pip install cryptodome` it returns this:

```
Collecting cryptodome
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cryptodome (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cryptodome
```

I've already tried updating pip, what should I do?

Comment: try using pip install pycryptodome

Answer (score 5):

working

```
pip3 install pycryptodomex
```

or

```
pip install pycryptodomex
```

if issus

```
sudo apt-get install pycryptodomex
```

(Debian linux)

Comment: This also works on windows (Python 3.8)

Comment: with Python 3.10 on linux pycrytodome was not enough.
pip install pycryptodomex made it work.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `pip install pycryptodome`.

Here is a link to the documentation: https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/

Comment: [A link to the documentation](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/installation.html) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the pycryptodome package instead,
go to command prompt and type in : pip3 install pycryptodome

pycryptodome documentation link: https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).